# Go JSON Naming strategy

Tags: json, go, marshalling, unmarshalling

I am very new in Go and I was exploring go to use for one of my micro services. I was wonder the way Go converts objects to Json and back to Json. But unfortunately i found configuring the output field names are little difficult with the use of tag names.

```
type MyStruct strust{
   MyName string
}
```

will converts to json

```
{
    "MyName" : "somestring"
}
```

But we are following a naming strategy for the whole api across Organization to follow snake_case

```
{
        "my_name" : "somestring"
}
```

Is considered to be valid in my org.

I started using the tags like `json:"my_name,omitempty"` etc per field level.

I would like to know is there a way i can configure it at global project level, so that i dont want to take care this at every object and its field level.

Comment: Is there any other go json library which I can use in this way. I don't think its good me to use golang then if i have to enter the names for db column and Json field name manually in the tags...I think its bigger drawback from a beautiful language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this: https://play.golang.org/p/Vn-8XH_jLp5

Core functionality:

```golang
// SnakeCaseEncode snake_case's the given struct's field names.
func SnakeCaseEncode(i interface{}) map[string]interface{} {
    rt, rv := reflect.TypeOf(i), reflect.ValueOf(i)

    if rt.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        i := reflect.Indirect(rv).Interface()
        rt, rv = reflect.TypeOf(i), reflect.ValueOf(i)
    }

    out := make(map[string]interface{}, rt.NumField())

    for i := 0; i < rt.NumField(); i++ {
        if rt.Field(i).Tag.Get("json") == "-" {
            continue
        }

        if strings.Contains(rt.Field(i).Tag.Get("json"), "omitempty") &&
            rv.Field(i).IsZero() { // Go 1.13
            continue
        }

        k := snakeCase(rt.Field(i).Name)

        out[k] = rv.Field(i).Interface()
    }

    return out
}

// snakeCase provides basic ASCII conversion of camelCase field names to snake_case.
func snakeCase(s string) string {
    out := make([]rune, 0, utf8.RuneCountInString(s))

    for i, r := range s {
        if r >= 'A' && r <= 'Z' {
            r += 32

            if i > 0 {
                out = append(out, '_')
            }
        }

        out = append(out, r)
    }

    return string(out)
}
```

To support map, slice etc. you'll have to expand on this simple version.

Comment: Please include code in the answer (at least the parts that show your principle).

Comment: Tried this...its looks nice....But i was expecting a well tested library for this purpose. Focusing on implementing this functionality for my project may lead un necessary delay on my project as i have to worry about all these stuffs in my project...i think its better to stick to some other language as of now... Thanks guys, Accepting this an answer as I am not able to see any other better solution than this.

Comment: @Ysak Talking about time delay: I assume the above code was written in less than half an hour, and giving it another hour it could be "production" ready. If you can't devote 2 hours to a core functionality, you'll have bigger problems than the matter of language choice...

Comment: I agree, I would not try it in my Org project, since currently our org have a full fledged Java and python support, which have been using for years...So spending time for this kind of add-ons is not grate idea...And I am not only considering  conversion of JSON...In future i may get deviated from building my business logic because of library support i may end up building supporting libraries, and even it includes deployment support as well.. Thinking from a enterprise project, its not just matter of 2 hour it may become more. And I am very new to GO ......